# Minimizing RSS by taking partial derivative

Tags: calculus, statistics, optimization, maxima-minima

I am learning about linear regression, and the goal is to find parameters $\beta$, that minimize the RSS. My textbook accomplishes this by finding $\partial \text{ RSS} /\partial \beta = 0$ However, I am slightly stuck on the following step:

They define:

$RSS(\beta) = (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\beta)^{T} (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta$,

where $\beta$ are scalars, $y$ is a column vector, and $X$ is a matrix.

They find that

$\frac{\partial RSS}{\partial \beta} = -2\mathbf{X}^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)$

I tried deriving this result. I first wrote:
$(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\beta)^{T} (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta) = (\mathbf{y}^{T} - \mathbf{X}^{T}\beta)(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\beta)$

I then expanded the two terms in brackets:
$\mathbf{y}^{T}\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{y}^{T}\mathbf{X}\beta - \mathbf{y}\mathbf{X}^{T}\beta + \mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}\beta^2$

Now, I differentiate this with respect to $\beta$:
$-\mathbf{y}^{T}\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{y}\mathbf{X}^{T} + 2\beta \mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}$

This is where I get stuck, comparing my result with the derived result, we both have the $2\beta \mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}$ term, but I don't know how my first 2 terms should simplify to give $-2\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{y}$.

Comment: Did you appreciate any of the answers? You should accept the best answer to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\beta$ is not a scalar, but a vector.

Let 
$$\mathbf{y} = \begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
\vdots \\
y_N
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12} & \cdots & x_{1p} \\
x_{21} & x_{22} & \cdots & x_{2p} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
x_{N1} & x_{N2} & \cdots & x_{Np}
\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$\beta = \begin{bmatrix}
b_1 \\
b_2 \\
\vdots \\
b_p
\end{bmatrix}\text{.}$$
Then $\mathbf{X}\beta \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and
$$\mathbf{X}\beta = \begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{1j} \\
\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{2j} \\
\vdots \\
\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{Nj}
\end{bmatrix} \implies \mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta=\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 - \sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{1j} \\
y_2 - \sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{2j} \\
\vdots \\
y_N - \sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{Nj}
\end{bmatrix} \text{.}$$
Therefore,
$$(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)^{T}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta) = \|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta \|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)^2\text{.} $$ 
We have, for each $k = 1, \dots, p$,
$$\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial b_k} = 2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)(-x_{ik}) = -2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{ik}\text{.}$$
Then
$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial \beta} &= \begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial b_1} \\
\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial b_2} \\
\vdots \\
\dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial b_p}
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=  \begin{bmatrix}
-2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{i1} \\
-2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{i2} \\
\vdots \\
-2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{ip}
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=  -2\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{i1} \\
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{i2} \\
\vdots \\
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_i-\sum_{j=1}^{p}b_jx_{ij}\right)x_{ip}
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=  -2\mathbf{X}^{T}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta)\text{.}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this very detailed derivation! Just a quick question: you have denoted as $x_{ip}$, above, which would mean that the transpose is $x_{pi}$, but in your final line, you don't have $x_{pi}$, but $x_{ip}$, so wondering where the $X^{T}$ comes from in the last equality.

Comment: @ThomasMoore I would recommend that you do the multiplication yourself to see that the above is true, but at a very simplistic level: remember that all you're doing when you're doing matrix multiplication is dot products of rows of the first matrix to columns of the second matrix. The $p$th column of $\mathbf{X}$ ends up being the $p$th row of $\mathbf{X}^T$ when you're doing the transposition. Thus, when you're performing a dot product between the $p$th row of $\mathbf{X}^{T}$  and $\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\beta$, ultimately, you're using all of the entries of the $p$th column of $\mathbf{X}$.

Answer (score 2):

The correct transpose (see [property 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose#Properties)) is $(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\beta)^{T} (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta) = (\mathbf{y}^{T} - \beta^T\mathbf{X}^{T})(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\beta)$

The correct expansion is $\mathbf{y}^{T}\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{y}^{T}\mathbf{X}\beta - \beta^T \mathbf{X}^{T} \mathbf{y} + \beta^T\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}\beta$

You can simplify the expansion to:
$$\mathbf{y}^{T}\mathbf{y} + (-\mathbf{X}^{T} \mathbf{y})^T \beta + (-\mathbf{X}^{T} \mathbf{y})^T \beta + \beta^T\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}\beta$$
And the result readily follows.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. But since $\beta$ is a scalar, isn't $\beta^T = \beta$?

Comment: @ThomasMoore my derivation applies both to scalars and to vectors; if you focus on scalars, your derivation goes wrong where you write $yX^T$ in the expansion: that is a matrix and should be $X^T y$. You can then use that $X^Ty = y^T X$.

Answer (score 2):

Expand the brackets to write
$$
\begin{align}
RSS(\beta)&=y'y-y'X\beta-\beta'X'y+\beta'X'X\beta\\
&=y'y-2\beta'X'y+\beta'X'X\beta
\end{align}
$$
where primes denote the transpose and $y'X\beta=\beta'X'y= (y'X\beta)'$ since $y'X\beta$ is a $1\times 1$ vector. Now we can differentiate to get that
$$
\frac{\partial RSS(\beta)}{\partial \beta}=-2X'y+2X'X\beta=-2X'(y-X\beta)
$$
Here we used  two properties. First, if $u=\alpha'x$ where $\alpha,x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then 
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}=\alpha_j\implies \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\alpha.
$$
One should notice that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ in this case represents the gradient. Second if $u=x'Ax=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij} x_{i} x_{j}$ where $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})
$
and $x\in\mathbb{R^n}$, then
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{\ell}}=\sum_{i=1}^na_{i\ell}x_{i}+\sum_{i=1}^na_{\ell i}x_{i}=[(A'+A)x]_{\ell}
\implies 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=(A'+A)x.
$$
In particular if $A$ is symmetric (like $X'X$ as above), we have that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=2Ax$

Answer (score 1):

Remark: $\beta$ is a vector.

In multiple regression, if you have $n$ independent variables, therefore you have $n+1$ parameters to estimate (included intercept), that is: $$y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1X_{1t}+...\beta_nX_{nt}+e_{t},$$ where each $\beta_{i}$ is scalar. 
We can write aforementioned with matrix notation (your problem is in matrix notation):
$$y=X\beta+e,$$
where $X$ is matrix, $y,\beta$ and $e$ are vectors! 
More precisely, $\beta_{i}$ is scalar, but $\beta$ is vector. Furthermore, you can note that unique solution of the problem that you have mentioned is the following:
$$\beta=(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}y,$$
where you can note easily that $\beta$ is a vector.